# Confused with syntax of String pointer to print values

Tags: arrays, c, string, pointers

I just learned pointers and I am quite confused with the syntax.

In my code, I've created a pointer variable ptr_int that points to int x[].
To print the value of the first element in the array, I would *ptr_int
To print the address of the first element in the array, I would use ptr_int

However, now I create a pointer variable str_ptr that points to an array of characters (string).

My question is,

1. Why can't I use *str_ptr to print the value of the first element in the array?
2. Why can't I use str_ptr to print the address of the first element in the array?
3. Why does str_ptr prints out the entire String? Doesn't str_ptr points to the address of the first element only?

   ```
    int x[5] = {1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    int *ptr_int;
    ptr_int = x;

    printf("\n\n The address of ptr_int is: %u", ptr_int);
    printf("\n The value of ptr_int is: %d", *ptr_int);

    char *str_ptr = "Character string to be printed";
    // Confused??
    printf("\n %s", str_ptr);
   ```

My expected output for str_ptr

1. *str_ptr = C
2. str_ptr = <address of first element, C>

Actual output

[image]

Comment: Post data as text not images.  Ask one question.  Post a [mre] instead of snippets.

Comment: "*str_ptr = C"  There is no `C` in the code.

Comment: "1. Why can't I ... 2. Why can't I ..." You can both and you are actually doing both. These question don't make sense. You use wrong format specifier for the address, though

Comment: @Gerhardh I realised that. That was my mistake

Answer (score 2, accepted):

0. The format string `%p` is used to print void pointers.  So it should be:

```
printf("\n\n The address of ptr_int is: %p", (void *) ptr_int);
```

1. If you want to print the first character you need to do either:

```
printf("%c\n", *str_ptr); // or
printf("%.1s\n", str_ptr);
```

2. In order to print the address of the first element in the array you would do:

```
printf("%p\n", (void *) str_ptr); // or
printf("%p\n", (void *) &str_ptr[0]);
```

3. A pointer to array points to the whole array. Pointer to first element of array points to a single value. Both pointers point to same memory address.

Comment: Nit pick about 3: _pointer to array_ points to the whole array. Pointer to first element of array points to a single value. Both pointers point to same memory address, but otherwise they should not be confused.

Comment: Thanks @hyde, updated answer.  They may be different types.

Comment: @AllanWind Hi, thanks for the reply. I have another question, why does  printf("\n The value of the entire string is: %s", *str_ptr);  gives a segmentation error?

Comment: @AllanWind Isn't the * operator used to get the value?

Comment: The format string `%s` expects a `char *`, and when you pass it  the variable `*str_ptr` it's of type `char`.  The `*` is used to deference the pointer.  Make sure you edit your question and replace the image with text.

Comment: @Issaki Value of  `*str_ptr` is ASCII value for C, 0x43. Using that as pointer tries to access that memory address, which is not allowed by the OS -> segmentation fault.

Comment: @Issaki Even worse, pointer is probably 8 bytes, while `*str_ptr` gets passes as 4 byte `int` to `printf` (because its variable argument function). So the pointer ends up being just garbage value.